# Python Guess Game

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, game

Estava fazendo um trabalho e me deparei com alguns problemas. 
Esse código possui uma limitação: Sempre que o jogador seleciona algum número que já foi selecionado antes o código não invalida e é considerado como uma tentativa. **Queria um help pra refinar o código e sempre que o jogador der um chute que ele já tenha dado anteriormente, o programa deverá recusá-lo e emitir uma mensagem informando ao jogador sobre essa situação e pedindo para ele tentar outro chute. Obviamente, esse chute duplicata não deverá ser contabilizado com uma das 10 tentativas que o jogador tem direito. Pensei em criar um array de 10 elementos mas me enrolei em como executar**

```
# apresente jogo ao usuário
print('Você tem 10 chances de acertar o número que eu estou pensando.')
print('Trata-se de um valor entre 1 e 100. Então, vamos lá!')
print()

# gere número-alvo entre 1 e 100
from random import randint
alvo = randint(1, 100)

# inicialize indicador de acerto
acertou = False

# repita 10 vezes:
contador = 0
while contador <= 10:

# obtenha palpite do usuário
while True:
try:
palpite = int(input('Entre o seu palpite: ')
if palpite < 1 or palpite > 100:
raise ValueError
break
except ValueError:
print('Palpite inválido. Tente outra vez!')
contador = contador + 1

# se palpite atingiu o alvo:
if palpite == alvo:

# atualize indicador de acerto
acertou = True

# encerre o jogo
break

# senão:
else:

# comunique erro ao usuário
print('Errou! Tente novamente.\n' \
'Você ainda tem ', 10-contador, ' tentativa(s).')
print(40*'-'+'\n')

# encerre o jogo
if acertou: # comunique sucesso ao usuário
print('Parabéns!\n' \
'Você acertou o número após ', contador, ' tentativa(s).')
else:

# comunique fracasso ao usuário
print('Infelizmente, você fracassou.\n', \
'O número pensado era: ', alvo, ' \n', \
'Quem sabe a próxima vez!')
print('Até breve') # emita saudação final
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difícil dizer o que está errado no seu código, ou até o que poderia ser melhorado, pois a indentação do seu código na pergunta prejudicou o entendimento. Se puder editar a pergunta corrigindo a indentação, poderei completar a resposta com comentários acerca da sua solução.

Como adendo, coloco uma maneira que eu resolveria o problema. Como você deseja que as tentativas sejam únicas, isto é, que o usuário não entre com o mesmo palpite mais de uma vez, de fato, você terá que armazená-los de alguma maneira. Para tal, utilizarei o `set` que, por padrão, já não permite valores duplicados.

> Retirarei as chamadas à função `print()` para simplificar o código, atentando-me somente à lógica implementada.

```
hunches = set()
```

Como descrito, existirão duas condições de paradas, exclusivas entre si: quando o usuário acertar o número sorteado; ou quando atingir o limite de 10 palpites. Assim, temos:

```
hit = False

while not hit and len(hunches) < 10:
    try:
        hunch = int(input('Seu palpite:'))
        ...
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```

Primeiro, validamos se o palpite está no intervalo aceitável:

```
hit = False

while not hit and len(hunches) < 10:
    try:
        hunch = int(input('Seu palpite:'))

        if not 1 <= hunch <= 100:
            raise ValueError('Palpite deve estar no intervalo [1, 100]')
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```

Depois, se o palpite já não foi dado anteriormente:

```
hit = False

while not hit and len(hunches) < 10:
    try:
        hunch = int(input('Seu palpite:'))

        if not 1 <= hunch <= 100:
            raise ValueError('Palpite deve estar no intervalo [1, 100]')

        if hunch in hunches:
            raise ValueError('Você já deu este palpite antes')
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```

Por fim, verificamos se o usuário acertou o número; se sim, definimos que acertou, mas se não, adicionamos o palpite ao conjunto de palpites:

```
hit = False

while not hit and len(hunches) < 10:
    try:
        hunch = int(input('Seu palpite:'))

        if not 1 <= hunch <= 100:
            raise ValueError('Palpite deve estar no intervalo [1, 100]')

        if hunch in hunches:
            raise ValueError('Você já deu este palpite antes')

        if hunch == target:
            hit = True
        else:
            hunches.add(hunch)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```

Ao final, podemos verificar se o usuário ganhou ou não:

```
print('Venceu' if hit else 'Perdeu')
```

O código completo ficaria:

```
from random import randint

target = randint(1, 100)

hit = False
hunches = set()

while not hit and len(hunches) < 10:
    try:
        hunch = int(input('Seu palpite:'))

        if not 1 <= hunch <= 100:
            raise ValueError('Palpite deve estar no intervalo [1, 100]')

        if hunch in hunches:
            raise ValueError('Você já deu este palpite antes')

        if hunch == target:
            hit = True
        else:
            hunches.add(hunch)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

print('Venceu' if hit else 'Perdeu')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/QuixoticModernTelevisions) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/a3e3be138eae1769f03eaa0a2828a75a)</sup>

Comment: Poooo valeu, tirou minha dúvida fiz de outra maneira mas agora tenho outro problema. Quero dar pistas e dicas para o usuário. Criei dois estados 1: quente e 2: frio. Sempre que o estado 1 e 2 forem iguais, o programa deverá emitir uma mensagem informando ao jogador que o estado do seu chute continua o mesmo, mas que deu uma esquentada ou uma esfriada em relação ao palpite anterior. E queria criar mais 3 estados para o palpite: Fervendo (FV), Morno (MN) e Congelando (CG), obedecendo essa ordem: FV –MQ –QT –MO –FR –MF –CG. O código não acusa erro, massssss não fornece essas dicas.

Comment: @RenatoSilva isso parece ser problema para outra pergunta já

Comment: Farei outra pergunta e colocarei o código então, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @RenatoSilva se a resposta lhe foi útil, busque votar e aceitá-la; veja como fazer em [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/5878)